# Vibrate iPhone while Recording

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, audio

I'm trying to get my iPhone to vibrate while I'm recording.

I've tried this:

```
UInt32 category = kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord; 
status |= AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof(category), &category);
UInt32 allowMixing = true;
status |= AudioSessionSetProperty (
      kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers,  // 1
      sizeof (allowMixing),                                 // 2
      &allowMixing                                          // 3
       );
status |= AudioSessionSetProperty(
      kAudioSessionProperty_OtherMixableAudioShouldDuck, // 1
      sizeof (allowMixing),        // 2
      &allowMixing          // 3
       );
```

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183366/play-alert-sound-vibrate-while-audioqueue-is-recording). Then vibrate the device later on by calling

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

<strike>But it does not work</strike>. But it does not vibrate. It records fine, and if I call a vibrate moments before I stop recording it vibrates after stop it.

Apparently it's a bug, does anyone know of a work around?

Comment: Seems like that would be a great way to reduce the quality of the recording...

Comment: Define "it does not work". Does it vibrate but not record? Does it record but not vibrate? Neither?

Comment: Quality is not an issue. I'm just doing some sound basic sound processing and vibrating after certain sounds. The user will never hear the audio thats being processed, it's never saved, etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

AT LAST! As of iOS 13, there is a new property on AVAudioSession

```
        let _ = try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playAndRecord)
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            let _ = try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setAllowHapticsAndSystemSoundsDuringRecording(true)
        }
```

Comment: This should be the answer!! Thanks mate

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that the vibration functions are specifically suppressed during audio recording. You could easily test this by doing something else that would normally make the phone vibrate (e.g. send yourself a text message with the mute switch on) while you are recording your audio—my bet is that it won't vibrate for that, either.

[This earlier thread confirms my view.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589294/iphone-does-not-vibrate-while-recording)

Comment: Forgot about this question. This answer will do. I actually overcame the problem with a bit of jailbreaking and some other jiggery-pokery.

Comment: can you please guid me... i am using MPMoviePlayerController and if i wan to record video withought any audio then can i vibrate my phone while recording the video???

Comment: here is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059607/how-to-use-vibration-while-recording-iphone5-ios... can you please see my question related to this